# add permission to read contact phonegap ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, permissions, contacts

I am working on a very simple ios app using phonegap/cordova. I want to add permission before starting reading from contact book. How to achieve this? I have tried to remove `<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>` but didn't work. Also tried to follow what is mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387007/phonegap-build-permissions-in-android) but without any luck. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts), I think it's what you wish :

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

Comment: I have that in my config.xml file but I don't see my app asks any permission before start reading the contact book.

Comment: I think you should follow an example that looks like what you are trying to achieve in the link I have provided and see eventually what you were doing wrong

Comment: Can you suggest such an example? Have tried to goggle a lot but no success. I have followed https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

Comment: I don't really know , but if you want to read a contact maybe finding one is close to what you want   but as I said I don't really know so the following may help you http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find