# phoneGap/Angular http request 404 error on phone while ok on browser

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, phonegap

I have angular app while reads webservices from my site, it is working fine on browser, but not on android.
I have build apk through [build.phonegap.com/apps](http://build.phonegap.com/apps/)

on phone it gives the following error

```
{"data":"","status":404,"config":
  {"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],
   "transformResponse":[null],"async":true,
    "url":"http://sub.example.com/api/items/1",
    "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}
  },
"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

my http requests code is

```
  $http({
        async : true,
        url: $scope.server+'/api/items/'+id,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.items = response.data;            
    },function myError(response) {
        $scope.error = response;
    });
```

on phone it is request to the right URL, I have copied url from error msg and checked it at chrome on phone, it is opening.

I have also added config.xml to root folder, it changed app title, icon etc but still not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.example.sub"
    versionCode = "1" 
    version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is Android only -->
    <!-- version is in major.minor.patch format --> 
    <name>my app</name>

    <description>
        A simple app
    </description>

    <author href="https://example.com" email="email@gmail.com">
        Fakhr-e-Alam
    </author>

    <access uri="http://*.example.com/" />


    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="icon.png" density="ldpi" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add network access permission into config.xml.

I found this on stackoverflow: [phonegap build permissions in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387007/phonegap-build-permissions-in-android)